# Getting exception when calling std::call_once

Tags: c++

I am trying a simple example to check the behavior of `std::call_once()`. I have tried the following code which doesn't do any useful work.

```
class Test {
  private:
    std::string obj_name;
    std::once_flag init_flag;

  public:
    Test(std::string name) : obj_name(name) {}

    void Init() {
        std::cout << "Initialization of " << obj_name << std::endl;
    }

    void Print() {
        try {
            std::call_once(init_flag, &Test::Init, this);
        } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Inside Print() of "<< obj_name << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test b1{"First object"};

    b1.Print();
    b1.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to see `Print()` called twice but getting an exception while calling `std::call_once()`. The output I got is -

```
Error: Unknown error -1
Inside Print() of First object
Error: Unknown error -1
Inside Print() of First object
```

To compile I've used -

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror
```

My question is why `std::call_once()` throwing exception? Or is it something I got wrong in my `Print()` method? If I change the body of `Print()` with just a return statement, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @S.M., gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

Comment: This is certainly a GCC bug

Comment: did you add `-pthread` flag to g++?

Comment: @N0ll_Boy, no I didn't. And as you said, it works after I add that. What could be the reason? I expected gcc to complain if proper flags not provided

Comment: @SomeNewbie it's probably gcc bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really strange bug. I saw it both on GCC and Clang.

Compile your code with `-pthread` and everything works.

I don't know why come compiles and runs, but it does not works correctly. I was expecting that code does not link. If you add `pthread`, it works as expected.

Comment: Strange. It did work but do you have any idea what is the reason behind it?

Comment: @SomeNewbie not really. it was strange for me too. For me, I thought that you should get link error and I don't know why this code links.

Comment: @SomeNewbie ```std::call_once``` is intended to be used with threads mostly (you call the same function from many threads, but want to execute it exactly once), so maybe they hadn't test it normally without threads :)

Comment: @KarenMelikyan problem is that why code links....if it uses any method(e.g. `pthread_once()`), you expect that code does not link.

Comment: @Afshin I guess they use conditional compilation using define directive, if ```pthread``` flag is set, only then it will compile code that uses such a method (and also includes, etc)

Answer (score 5):

This is a GCC/libstdc++ bug, compile with `-pthread` to fix. See: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55394

Comment: same thing happened for clang too, so not for gcc only.

Comment: More correctly it's a libstdc++ bug I suppose